# Issue with root localhost directory wamp

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I just installed `wamp` on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. I previously had IIS installed on this machine so I disabled it. The issue I'm having is I cannot browse `localhost` I get

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Note* I cannot browse to `127.0.0.1` either. Same error.

However, I can browse these directories with no issues.

```
[PhpMyAdmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin)  
[SqlBuddy](http://localhost/sqlbuddy)  
[PhpSysInfo](http://localhost/phpsysinfo)
```

The `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` does contain the following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A likely cause is that the webserver has no permission to read the root www directory.

Have you tried checking your vhosts.conf file? It should be somewhere in

```
[your wamp dir]/bin/apache/[apache vers]/conf/extra
```

There check if there is a default virtual host available. There should be one configured by the default install.

Then check the directory pointed by the *DocumentRoot* directive exists and is readable/writable.

Comment: An example of a virtual host would help a ton.